# Android GCM- Manifest File and Registration

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented a project with GCM before. I want to create a new project now, I need a new project id and i got it but now i can not register. Is it about project id? or Can i use previous project id?

And last question:

```
<category android:name="my_app_package" />   

<permission android:name="my_app_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="my_app_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

What is app package name? is it at the top of the manifest file? or is it that includes GCM java pages?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <!-- The targetSdkVersion is optional, but it's always a good practice
         to target higher versions. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!--
     Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

     NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
           where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.ketan.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.ketan.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ketan.demo.DemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--
          BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.ketan.demo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--
          Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
          handle received messages.

          By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
          application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
        -->
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've implemented the GCM so refer the manifest file for that.

Comment: your pkg name does not match with android:name="com.ketan.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE".

Comment: @GooGLE and Vineet Shukla i understand it my package name is different. I write manifest file as yours, but still i get empty registration id. what can i do else?

Comment: then you have to paste the code in so so i can see what you have actually done so

Comment: GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this); GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this); String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this); if (regId.equals("")) { GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); } else { MyLog.log("Already registered"); } regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this); MyLog.log("register id ="+regId); System.out.println("Get Reg ID: " + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));

Comment: when i watch logcat, i can see **09-11 13:22:14.708: D/GCMRegistrar(19154): resetting backoff for com.example.push
09-11 13:22:14.708: V/GCMRegistrar(19154): Registering app com.example.push of senders 668788400385** at GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); and register id always returns empty string.

Answer (score 0):

First,if you wanna register again - you should unregister.

The app package is neeeded for gcm service.
Register your GCMBroadcastReceiver with it.

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="my_app_package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use previous projectID but when you send notification the other application that uses projectID can also receive the notifications if you register it previously.

You should be able to use new project id. Maybe you make something wrong.Check it again.

For your second question, app_package is the main package of your application.

Comment: thank you, but still i get empty registration id, i can not register, what can i do else?

Comment: GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);   GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this); String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);               if (regId.equals("")) { GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); } else { MyLog.log("Already registered"); }                       regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);      MyLog.log("register id ="+regId);               System.out.println("Get Reg ID: " + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));

Comment: @pervin i registered at another project with the same code, but now it is not working. is it about project id? i think my manifest file is true, too.

Comment: when i watch logcat, i can see **09-11 13:22:14.708: D/GCMRegistrar(19154): resetting backoff for com.example.push 09-11 13:22:14.708: V/GCMRegistrar(19154): Registering app com.example.push of senders 668788400385** at GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); and register id always returns empty string.

Comment: How you declare GCMIntentService? Check that you have public no argument constructor there. It should look like : public GCMIntentService(){super(senderID);}

Comment: hi parvin, i put GCMIntentService class in main package and it works now. Does GCMIntentService only work in main package?

Comment: no you can put it different package but you should set its package correctly in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to follow this link for GCM
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Each and every project has package name and its project Id for GCM.
If you not specify the project's package name then you can use previous project id for notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting response from the registration.one of the main reason is your manifest file is not configured correctly...especially give the "package_name"(your app package name like com.xxx.yyy) in the and correctly.